# Finding the max values of each subset in pandas

Tags: pandas, max

I'm trying to divide each value by the max value for the given year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fiscal Year': {0: 2020, 1: 2019, 2: 2021, 3: 2020, 4: 2021},
 'Product Num': {0: 'widget', 1: 'doodad', 2: "widget", 3: 'doodad', 4: 'widget'},
 'Value': {0: 1000, 1: 1100, 2: 900, 3: 1300, 4: 800}})
```

So,

```
Product  |   Year    |   New Value 
Widget   |   2020    |   .769
Doodad   |   2019    |     1
Widget   |   2021    |     1
Doodad   |   2020    |     1
Widget   |   2021    |   .889
```

I know I can do groupby's and then go through each entry and figure it out that way, but that doesn't seem efficient.   Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I recommend you go through the pandas "10 minutes to pandas" docs page. It covers the so-called split-apply-combine workflow is pretty good detail

Comment: `df['New Value'] = df['Value'] / df.groupby('Fiscal Year')['Value'].transform('max')`